# How do I display the output of a function of multiple qualtrics sliders in real time?

Tags: slider, qualtrics, computation

My colleague and I am designing a survey using Qualtrics. On one page respondents must move a series of sliders.
We need to display the output of a function of the values of the sliders on the same page, ideally also in the form of another slider.
All of this must be done *while* the respondent moves the sliders.

Concretely, suppose the following:

```
value of slider 1 = 30;
value of slider 2 = 10;
value of slider 3 = 0

Output to be displayed = 30 x 20 + 10 x 5 + 0 x 15 = 650
```

where the 20, 5 and 15 are just arbitrary constants in the background.

If the user were to move slider 1 to 31, the displayed output should automatically update in real time to 670.

Any tip on how this is done? We're newbies to qualtrics and completely inexperienced with Java, so we'd be very grateful to anyone willing to provide us with working code. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but you are unlikely to get what you asked for. The intent of stackoverflow is for programmers to help other programmers.  It isn't a free programming service.  It is expected that actually try to create the code yourself and post that code as part of your question.

Comment: I had immagined, and I'm sorry if I came across in the wrong way. What I am asking for Is for anything that might allow us to get on. A bit of code perhaps upon which we can start working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update on my question, and a clarification after a comment received.
We were of course not asking for someone else to do our job. Just for a pointer in the right direction.

Based on an answer to a different question, I've managed to put this javascript together. It works, which is encouraging.. 
Code follows.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is fully displayed*/
var that=this.questionId;
   jQuery("<p style='width:100%'><br><strong> Output <span id='OUT'>0</span></strong>").insertAfter("table.sliderGrid");
    jQuery(document).on('change', function(){

        var firstslider=parseInt(jQuery("[id='"+that+"~1~result']").val());
        var secondslider=parseInt(jQuery("[id='"+that+"~2~result']").val());
        var N=firstlider+secondslider*2;
        jQuery("#OUT").text(N);
    });
```